# How to send parameters to Azure runbook api

Tags: groovy, azure-automation

We are using Azure automation and groovy script from Scriptrunner to create different jobs based on different Runbook

For that we are using the following API call sample

```
http.request(PUT) {
            requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
            headers.'Authorization' = "Bearer " + AuthToken 
            body = ['properties': ['runbook': ['name': Runbook],'parameters':['Vm': Env], 'runOn': 'devops']]
```

The way we format the body here is working  ok when we need to hard code a single parameter named Vm in our case which set from an Env parameter string

The issue we met actually is that this **parameters** section of the body can have more than 1 single parameters and different parameter name.

For example the following body can be possible too depending on different use case :

```
body = ['properties': ['runbook': ['name': Runbook],'parameters':[**'Vm': Env, 'Path': absolute, 'Target':test01**], 'runOn': 'devops']]
```

What I am trying to do, is to build the parameters section has a variable that I can then place as part of the body as bellow

```
body = ['properties': ['runbook': ['name': Runbook],'parameters':[$paramList], 'runOn': 'devops']]
```

$paramList is a string which contains "'Vm': Env, 'Path': absolute, 'Target':test01"

For some reason it does not work, what did I miss on building that string and injecting in the parameters section of the body value ?

Thanks for help
regards

Comment: I think you want `[... parameters: parameterList, ...]`

Comment: what do you mean ?
What I am trying to do is to build the content of the json array 'parameters' dynamically. I have try to define a string with "['vm': Env]" but it return a Bad Request error.
Any idea how to format that alue to be injected into the parameters array?

Comment: This is not a string, but a map-literal in Groovy

Comment: @cfrick, you mean I need to define my parameters as  : Map param=['Vm1': Env1,'Vm2': Env2] and then body = ['properties': ['runbook': ['name': Runbook],'parameters':param, 'runOn': 'devops']], is that what you mean?

Comment: @cfrick, I have change it to Map and inject it in the body and it works as expected. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as explain by @cfrick was to use Map object as below.
I need to define my dynamique parameters as :

```
Map myParams=['Vm1': Env1,'Vm2': Env2]
```

Then injecte the Map object as part of the global body :

```
body = ['properties': ['runbook': ['name': Runbook],'parameters':myParams, 'runOn': 'devops']]
```